# Misunderstanding Python bytes with files and regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to modify byte data, my files are read using the `b` modifier.

Sometimes the search will contain a wildcard, so I am using `re` - it supports byte patterns.

For example

```
re.finditer(b'\x00\x01\x00\x03\x7c', file)
```

My problem is that `\x7c` is interpereted as the `|` operator in regex.

In all my other cases the byte search works fine, how do I stop `re` parsing this? Am I misunderstanding `re` or byte data?

Thanks!

```
> python --version
Python 3.8.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting an escape character into the regex (the backslash `\x5c`) to escape the pipe should work:

```
re.finditer(b'\x00\x01\x00\x03\x5c\x7c', file)
```

Worth noting is that you can input string/character literals in bytestrings and they work fine, which makes it slightly more comprehensible:

```
re.finditer(b'\x00\x01\x00\x03\|', file)
```

Or you could use `re.escape()` first, which is a more extensible and general-purpose solution:

```
re.finditer(re.escape(b'\x00\x01\x00\x03\x7c'), file)
```

Comment: Thank you! `re.escape` was what I needed. Interestingly I was also `print`ing for debug but it still actually shows the `|` even though the regex works properly now.